# req.cookies in express is not being populated

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, passport.js

I am setting a session cookie as part of PassportJS.  I can see the connect.sid cookie being passed to the browser, and back to the application on subsequent HTTP requests.

However, when I read req.cookies in one of my routes, it is empty.  I have set up express.cookieParser(), express.session(), and passport.session() in configuration settings.  Is there anything else that needs to be done in order to use cookies in Express / Node?

Here are my app configuration settings:

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.set("db_url", config.db[app.settings.env]);
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));  /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret: "keyboard cat"}));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(users);
  app.use(orgs);
  app.use(errorHandler);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could have given the link to this video http://vimeo.com/56166857 , TJ comments are pretty useful

Answer (score -1):

Try `req.session` instead `req.cookies`. If you want to store information within the cookie you need to set them similar to

```
res.cookie('remember', 1, { maxAge: 60 * 1000 });
```

Then `req.cookies` should contain

```
{ remember: '1' }
```

The default value of `req.session` is

```
{ cookie: 
  { path: '/',
    _expires: null,
    originalMaxAge: null,
    httpOnly: true
  }
}
```